# Android play with Toast in switch between every fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm trying to simply play with toasts and check how to show Toasts when I'm switching between fragments. For example I have two fragments in `PagerTabStrip` as fragment1 and fragment2.

Visiting fragments for the first time makes the toast visible and switching to second fragment makes the toasts visible twice.

Any help would greatly be appreciated!!

**summurized code**

FragmentOne:

```
public class FragmentOne extends Fragment {
    public static FragmentOne newInstance(int page) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt("page", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_list, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
         Toast.makeText(G.context,"fragment 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
         Toast.makeText(G.context,"fragment 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

FragmentTwo:

```
public class FragmentTwo extends Fragment {
    public static FragmentTwo newInstance(int page) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        page = getArguments().getInt("page", 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_group_list, container, false);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
         Toast.makeText(G.context,"fragment 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
         Toast.makeText(G.context,"fragment 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: @KarolŻygłowicz ok. just a minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an `OnPageChangeListener` for your `ViewPager` using `setOnPageChangeListener()`.

```
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
              //show your Toasts here
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });
```